# VS2022 - Input issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

Either something has come undone in my brain overnight, or there has been a change to my instance of Visual Studio that I made by accident. I was running v17.3.1 and just updated to v17.3.4 to see if it would fix the issue, but it has not.

For the last few years of pushing out lines of sub-optimal code, I have gotten a space when I pressed the spacebar and a period when I push the period button. I use intellisense a great deal, to the point that when I want to log something, I type `logger.in[tab]` and I get `logger.LogInformation` written, waiting for me to type what I want logged.

This morning, my code was way worse than usual. I wasn't getting spaces or periods being typed to the screen. Initially, I thought it was my keyboard, but a quick test showed that my keyboard was fine. Then I noticed that when I would press either the period or spacebar buttons, the intellisense would complete the selection but not insert the space or the period.

Even trying to create a new variable is painful. Typing `string[space]myString` leaves me with `stringmyString` in the IDE.

Double tapping the space or period button feels really unnatural to me. Does anyone know what options I may have accidently changed, or how I can get it back to how it was working yesterday?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I thought I had fixed it with `Edit -> Intellisense -> Switch between automatic and tab-only Intellisense completion`, but then I had to double click on the autocomplete that I wanted for it to insert it.

Comment: I update the VS2022 and make test like you but I can't reproduce the problem. You can try the following method maybe can help you: 1. Open Visual Studio Installer and Repair the VS. 2. Go to Tools>Import and Export Settings to Reset all settings. Hope that can help you.

Comment: There is a feedback button in VS, that I used to report this same problem.

Comment: I was just being frustrated and unable to google anything about it myself until I ran across this.  I will definitely use your workaround as I use tab primarily anyway, but this has got to be a bug with the new update.

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT I have reset settings and exported settings from a PC that is working as intended and imported them to the instance that is not working. Still same issue. Testing for nulls is driving me insane. `if(object[spacex2]is[spacex2]not[spacex2]null)`.

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT, A repair worked. Now I can enjoy my Saturday knowing that Monday is going to be a lot better. Thanks.

Comment: This issue seems to be related to a Telerik extension. In my case, disabling that fixed it.

Comment: See https://feedback.telerik.com/blazor/1579953-telerik-ui-for-blazor-3-6-0-breaks-intellisense-typing-in-visual-studio-2022-version-17-3-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the visual studio installer and Repair the VS it will solve the problem.

Comment: A "Repair" apparently removes all "per-user extensions", which undoubtedly will include the Telerik extension that seems to be the cause. I haven't tried repair + reinstall that Telerik extension

Answer (score 1):

This issue was caused by the Telerik extension, in my case "Progress Telerik UI for Blazor". This was [reported](https://feedback.telerik.com/blazor/1579953-telerik-ui-for-blazor-3-6-0-breaks-intellisense-typing-in-visual-studio-2022-version-17-3-4) to Telerik, who quickly published a new version.

The new version of the extension (2022.3.921.3) fixed this issue.